# SWI-Prolog: how to insert a new clause to a database

Tags: prolog

I'm sorry, this has probably been asked before but I can't find a good answer.

I'm writing a Prolog assignment, in which we must write a database with insert, delete, etc. I'm currently stuck on the insert part. I'm trying to use tell, listing and told for this, but the results are often unpredictable, deleting random parts of the file. Here's the full code of my database, `banco.pl`:

```
:- dynamic progenitor/2.
progenitor(maria,joao).
progenitor(jose,joao).
progenitor(maria,ana).
progenitor(jose,ana).

insere(X,Y) :- dynamic progenitor/2, assert(progenitor(X,Y)).
tell('banco.pl'), listing(progenitor), told.
```

I then run the following on SWI-Prolog:

```
insere(luiz,luiza).
```

And get the following result on `banco.pl`:

```
:- dynamic progenitor/2.

progenitor(maria, joao).
progenitor(jose, joao).
progenitor(maria, ana).
progenitor(jose, ana).
```

Note that the clause I tried to insert isn't even in the file, and the lines defining commit and insere are missing.

How would I do this correctly?

Comment: You have a typo in your definition of the `insere/2` predicate. There's a `.` (end of clause) instead of a `,` (conjunction) at the  end of the first line of the predicate definition.

Comment: The expression `dynamic progenitor/2` doesn't belong in a predicate clause (`insere/2` in this case) since it's a directive, and you've already issued the directive at the start of the program. I'm surprised you didn't get an error message.

Comment: Are you required to use Edinburg-style IO?

Answer (score 0):

`tell` starts writing to the beginning of the file. so you're overwriting everything else that was in the file. you have these options:

1. put your `progenitor` predicate (and just that) in another file.
2. use `append/1` to write to the end of the file with `portray_clause`. this only helps for `insert`, but you stated that you want `delete` too.
3. read the other clauses into a list and reprint them, then use `listing/1` :

(text for formatting)

```
read_all_other_clauses(All_Other_Clauses):-
  see('yourfilename.pl'),
  read_all_other_clauses_(All_Other_Clauses,[]),
  seen.

read_all_other_clauses_(Other,Acc0):-
  (read(Clause) ->
   (Clause = progenitor(_,_) -> % omit those clauses, because they'll be printed with listing/1
     read_all_other_clauses_(Other,Acc0);
     read_all_other_clauses_(Other,[Clause|Acc0]));
   Other = Acc0). % read failed, we're done

operation(Insert, X,Y):-
    (call,(Insert) ->
      assert(progenitor(X,y));
      retract(progenitor(X,y))),
    read_all_other_clauses(Others),
    tell('yourfilename.pl'), % After the reading!
    maplist(portray_clause,Others), %Maplist is a SWI built-in, easy to rewrite, if you don't have it.
    listing(progenitor/2),
    told.

insert(X,Y):- operation(true,X,Y).
delete(X,Y):- operation(fail,X,Y).
```

Note that you could use the `read_all_other_clauses` for your `delete` only, if you change the line with the omit comment. Then you could use the solution proposed in #2 for your `insere`