# Retracting and asserting to another file in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-directive-dynamic

I'm trying to retract and assert a fact in another file. One (fruit1.pl) contains a couple of facts, and another (fruit.pl) contains a predicate `start` which designates which fact that another predicate `insert_fruit` will update:

**fruit1.pl**

```
fruit(apple, [[2, yellow], [1, brown]]).
fruit(orange, [[3, orange], [2, orange]]).
```

**fruit.pl**

```
:- dynamic fruit/2.

start :-
    consult('fruit1.pl'),
    File = 'fruit1.pl',
    Name = apple,
    Price = 2,
    Color = red,
    insert_fruit(File, Name, Price, Color). 

insert_fruit(File, Name, Price, Color) :-
   open(File, update, Stream),
   retract(fruit(Name, Information)),
   assert(fruit(Name, [[Price, Color]|Information])),
   close(Stream).
```

However `insert_fruit` is not working as intended, as I believe it needs to include Stream to modify the other file, although I have no idea how (`retract(Stream, ...)` doesn't work). Is there some I would be able to get the retract and assert predicates to function in the other file?

Comment: What you are trying is not going to work like this. `assert` and `retract` manipulate the predicate "database", not a file that is currently open. You have asked a similar question before and got a comment and an answer; read them.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278667/swi-prolog-how-to-insert-a-new-clause-to-a-database)? I gave an answer there. Also, what Boris said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog you can assert/retract facts from a file that is used as a persistent fact store by using [library `persistency`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/persistency.pl):

1. You declare `fruit/3` as persistent. Optionally: you annotate the arguments with a type for automatic type checking.
2. You attach a file that will serve as the persistent fact store upon initialization of the `fruit` module (in this case `fruit1.pl`).
3. You add predicates for inserting (i.e., `add_fruit/3`) and querying (i.e., `current_fruit/3`) fruity facts. Retraction is handled similarly.
4. Notice that you can use the fact store in a multi-threaded environment by using `with_mutex/2` (especially useful when you start retracting facts as well).

#### Code

```
:- module(
  fruit,
  [
    add_fruit/3, % +Name:atom, +Price:float, +Color:atom
    current_fruit/3 % ?Name:atom, ?Price:float, ?Color:atom
  ]
).

:- use_module(library(persistency)).

:- persistent(fruit(name:atom, price:float, color:atom)).

:- initialization(db_attach('fruit1.pl', [])).

add_fruit(Name, Price, Color):-
  with_mutex(fruit_db, assert_fruit(Name, Price, Color)).

current_fruit(Name, Price, Color):-
  with_mutex(fruit_db, fruit(Name, Price, Color)).
```

#### Illustration of use

Start Prolog, load `fruit.pl`, execute:

```
?- add_fruit(apple, 1.10, red).
```

Close Prolog, start Prolog (again), execute:

```
?- current_fruit(X, Y, Z).
X = apple,
Y = 1.1,
Z = red
```

You are now reading facts from `fruit1.pl`!

#### Illustration of automatic type checking

As mentioned before, the library also performs type checking for you, e.g.:

```
?- add_fruit(pear, expensive, green).
ERROR: Type error: `float' expected, found `expensive' (an atom)
```

Comment: Hi Wouter, nice answer. Do you know if QLF is supported ?

Comment: @CapelliC Do you mean Quasi-Logical Form? I'm not familiar with that, nor sure how it would apply here... Could you give an example of a QLF w.r.t. a persistent store?

Comment: no, much lower level... [Quick Load Format](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=qlf)

Comment: Thank you for the very insightful response!